# Como são implementadas as funções das bibliotecas padrões de diferentes linguagens de programação?

Tags: java, c

Como são implementadas as bibliotecas padrões das diferentes linguagens de programação? Por exemplo, `stdlib.h`, ou `Java.Swing`, como é implementada a função `System.out.prinln()` por exemplo.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Acho que a pergunta até pode ficar interessante Rodrigo. Tens é de ser mais especifico no que pretendes. O [stackoverflow](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) é um site de perguntas diretas para respostas diretas, tentando não entrar muito na opinião. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Normalmente a votaria para fechar a pergunta, mas irei deixar a comunidade decidir.

Comment: Eu acho que é amplo demais. Sugiro focar em um problema específico, por exemplo, essa implementação do `stdlib.h`. Você pode **[edit]** a pergunta para deixá-la conforme os padrões do site detalhados na [help].

Comment: Já editei a postagem pra tentar me focar primeiro em uma coisa.

Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @RodrigoApp, removi o texto não relacionado, por favor, foque no problema técnico (o [tour] do site é bastante explicito à respeito disso, pois se considera isso como ruído). Você chegou a tentar implementar a função? Se sim, poste seu código e explique seu problema com ele.

Comment: Não cheguei não. Não saberia por onde começar. Teria que ser implementado em C mesmo? Ou em linguagem de baixo nível?

Comment: @brasofilo o RodrigoApp veio perguntar em um grupo no Facebook como seria implementar uma função que mostrasse um pixel na tela. Eu disse que a pergunta dele seria muito apreciada se ele fizesse a pergunta aqui no SOpt. Acho que ele não quer saber como implementar a função em uma determinada linguagem, mas sim entender o conceito por trás de mostrar um pixel na tela manipulando a VRAM. É isto RodrigoApp?

Comment: @Avelino, ah, pois isso é importante estar na pergunta então.

Comment: Bem, se é isso que ele quer, ele poderia fazer uma outra pergunta e deixar essa salva.

Comment: Eu acho que é melhor entender como são implementadas funções como printf() e scanf() e depois entender como são implementadas funções como as que fazem imagens.

Answer (score 5):

## Onde começar:

Sempre procure implementações abertas das linguagens que quer descobrir como algo funciona.
Em geral para cada plataforma as coisas são implementadas de forma diferente e no caso de C, sim precisará de trabalhar em certo nível mais baixo, o que pode ser desde ASM ou até mesmo um `subset` da linguagem C.

## Java

Em Java, apesar da JDK/JRE da Oracle ser fechada, há a OpenJDK, na qual pode encontrar a implementação de funções padrões como o `System.out.println()`

**System.out.println()**

Vamos analisar de forma básica como é feito o callback, ou todas as chamadas (em um nível um pouco mais abstrato) da mesma:

[image: Nível abstrato fluxograma da println]

E pode ver todas as funções chamadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver, a função é feita de forma o mais genérica possível e tanto quanto possível, mas sempre acaba precisando de chegar no nível mais baixo `JNI` que é onde o Java se comunica com C e faz as chamadas de sistema.

E só para você ter uma noção de como é o nível mais baixo (não quero deixar esta resposta longa demais) irei postar o que ocorre na JNI que está definido no arquivo [io_util.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/1ad7fbef48d0/src/share/native/java/io/io_util.c)

```c
void
writeBytes(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jbyteArray bytes,
           jint off, jint len, jfieldID fid)
{
    jint n;
    char stackBuf[BUF_SIZE];
    char *buf = NULL;
    FD fd;
 
    if (IS_NULL(bytes)) {
        JNU_ThrowNullPointerException(env, NULL);
        return;
    }
 
    if (outOfBounds(env, off, len, bytes)) {
        JNU_ThrowByName(env, "java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException", NULL);
        return;
    }
 
    if (len == 0) {
        return;
    } else if (len > BUF_SIZE) {
        buf = malloc(len);
        if (buf == NULL) {
            JNU_ThrowOutOfMemoryError(env, NULL);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        buf = stackBuf;
    }
 
    (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, bytes, off, len, (jbyte *)buf);
 
    if (!(*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env)) {
        off = 0;
        while (len > 0) {
            fd = GET_FD(this, fid);
            if (fd == -1) {
                JNU_ThrowIOException(env, "Stream Closed");
                break;
            }
            n = IO_Write(fd, buf+off, len);
            if (n == JVM_IO_ERR) {
                JNU_ThrowIOExceptionWithLastError(env, "Write error");
                break;
            } else if (n == JVM_IO_INTR) {
                JNU_ThrowByName(env, "java/io/InterruptedIOException", NULL);
                break;
            }
            off += n;
            len -= n;
        }
    }
    if (buf != stackBuf) {
        free(buf);
    }
}
```

Claro que ainda desce um pouco mais, mas aí já fica dependendo do Sistema Operacional, visto que Linux, Windows e BSDs precisam de implementações diferentes. Mas esse é o ponto mais baixo e comum da função que pediu como exemplo (`System.out.println()`).